# What is the relationship between the port type and the symmetric type returned by stunclient？

Tags: nat, stun

Running the stun command you can see that the description returned will indicate whether the port is a `preserves port` or a `random port` and that b0 will also indicate whether it is a `preserves port` or a `random port`.
And b3 is a description of whether the NAT type is symmetric or not symmetric?
As I understand it, all Cone type NATs are `preserves port` and all symmetric type ones are `random port`. Isn't this a duplicate description?

Can someone tell me what exactly is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 0):

Symmetric type has many different algorithms as for realising, it depends on the kernel code, and it always shows like random or increase, you can see your OS' kernel code for deep understand.

Comment: thanks @tyChen, would you please explain such a result: Primary: Independent Mapping, Port Dependent Filter, random port, will hairpin
Return value is 0x000006

Comment: I'm confused about your problem, I can't understand what you want to ask.